# ASP.NET MVC service layer complex authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, security, authorization

I have a question about authorization/Validation a user Action before doing any database updates in a Service layer.

I have a JobPostingController which provides methods to create/update/delete a Job posting.

I want a user only able to update/delete a Job posting when he is the owner of the Entity. (Have something like JobPostingOwner in my JobPosting Entity)

Is there an easy way to create custom Controller Action filters to achieve this?

From my understanding the check if a user is allowed to update/delete a specific Entity should be in the Service layer but have no idea if there is an easier way than

```
public void UpdateJobPosting(JobPosting jobPosting, User user)
{
    if(jobPostingOwnerId == user.Id) --> OK
    else --> not OK
}
```

Another simple example:

```
/JobPosting/Edit/(id)
```

I want to always check if a user is really allowed to edit this Job posting.
So in the Service layer I would do:

```
public JobPosting GetJobPosting(int id, User user)
{
    var query = from item in context.JobPostings
                where item.id == id
                && item.OwnerId == user.Id
                select item;

    ....
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this or is there another pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a method like this in your service layer:

```
public bool IsUserAllowed(int potingId, User user)
{
            var query = from item in context.JobPostings
                        where item.id == potingId
                        && item.OwnerId == user.Id
                        select item;
            var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
            return result != null;
}
```

Then create a custom action filter (a class named `CustomActionFilterAttribute` derived from `AuthorizeAttribute`), inside `AuthorizeCore` method you can simply check for user's permission:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
            base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
            var jobPostingId = (routeData.Values["id"] as string) ?? (httpContext.Request["id"] as string);
            var user = UserManager.FindUser(httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
            return _jobPosting.IsUserAllowed(int.Parse(jobPostingId), user);
}
```

Finally, you have to decorate your `Edit` action method with the custom action filter:

```
[CustomActionFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  // ....
}
```